# Will subdomain and Wordpress interfere with eachother?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, web-hosting

I’m having someone redo my blog. It’s  in WordPress. But I'm creating my main site using a different custom Wordpress theme. Both this site and the blog will end up in the same GoDaddy hosting account. I plan to have the blog in a subdirectory with a sub-URL (e.g. blog.example.com). Will these two WordPress sites interfere with each other or will they work independently?

Comment: You should use WordPress in MultiSite mode. Read this for more info http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having two Wordpress installations for similar tasks is not a good practice for various reasons like maintenance, usage of resources, upgrades, security, etc.

Wordpress allows you to have custom designs for every Post type, can't you put your Blog inside your site by changing the design of the single page and the loop of that specific post type?

As the comment above says, there's the possibility to [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and with this have a central installation separated by many domains / subdomains or folders. I used this in the past and found it great.

If you can't for any reason use any of the resources above, then the answer to your question is no, they will not interfere with each other as they are independent installations.